# Filling NaN values based on values of row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dummy dataframe:

```
City       Longitude     Latitude
new mexico  1.94          2.34
berlin       2.44         5.33
london       1.1           2.44
new mexico    nan          nan
tokyo         2.2          3.3
berlin        nan           nan
new york      2.5           1.44
dakota         2             5.4
jakarta        3.4           4.5
london         nan           nan
```

Some cities are listed more than once but, the repeated cities have missing values.
I want to fill the nan values for some cities in longitude and latitude columns using the values of the same cities, I have tried using ffil and backward fill but, it did not work as the missing value do not follow a pattern.

Comment: Please edit your post to contain the code that you tried to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by your `Longitude` and `Latitude` columns so that `NaN`s are at the bottom, then use `groupby` and `ffill`, finally re-sorting by your index:

```
df.sort_values(['Longitude', 'Latitude']).groupby('City').ffill().sort_index()

         City  Longitude  Latitude
0  new mexico       1.94      2.34
1      berlin       2.44      5.33
2      london       1.10      2.44
3  new mexico       1.94      2.34
4       tokyo       2.20      3.30
5      berlin       2.44      5.33
6    new york       2.50      1.44
7      dakota       2.00      5.40
8     jakarta       3.40      4.50
9      london       1.10      2.44
```

Or better yet, just sort by `City` first, then `Longitude` and `Latitude`, and use `ffill` without the groupby:

```
df.sort_values(['City','Longitude', 'Latitude']).ffill().sort_index()

         City  Longitude  Latitude
0  new mexico       1.94      2.34
1      berlin       2.44      5.33
2      london       1.10      2.44
3  new mexico       1.94      2.34
4       tokyo       2.20      3.30
5      berlin       2.44      5.33
6    new york       2.50      1.44
7      dakota       2.00      5.40
8     jakarta       3.40      4.50
9      london       1.10      2.44
```

Comment: Many Thanks sacul, I really appreciate it.